# How do I put the results of each group on one row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select id, productid, optionid 
from tableA
where productid = 1
```

result (id, productid, optionid)

```
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 5
```

I would like the result to be (productid, optionids):

```
1 1,2,5
```

Naturally, I would think the query below should produce the above result

```
select productid, optionid 
from tableA
group by productid
```

But what function do I put optionid in?

Comment: Have you looked at the Pivot clause?

Comment: No, first time hearing of it.

Comment: This has been asked many, many times before. Just do a quick search with sql-server and group concatenation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` (with some help from `STUFF` function) to do that. You cannot group as there's sadly no aggregate function for concatenating strings.

```
select distinct a.productid,
stuff((select ','+cast(s.optionid as varchar(10))
       from tableA s 
       where s.productid = a.productid 
       for XML path('')),1,1,'')
from tableA a
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3635/5)

Comment: +1 to the answer, but please don't say it like the `STUFF` function is doing the concatenation, since it's simply removing the extra comma. It's the `XML PATH` which makes this possible.

Comment: Very true, I'll update my answer. Thanks a lot!